# Change url using htaccess wont work

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hi I am trying to change my url using htaccess but it didn't work anymore.

*`http://localhost:8888/cPanel/abc?page=general-settings`*

```
RewriteRule ^cPanel/([\w-]+)/?$ abc.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

What i am doing wrong anyone can help me here please ?

I want to change the url like this:

**`http://localhost:8888/cPanel/general-settings`**

```
<?php 
$page ='';
if($_GET['page']){ 
    $page = $_GET['page'];
 if($page == 'general-settings'){
     include "/pages/general-settings.php" ;
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: So, what happens when you're trying to access `http://localhost:8888/cPanel/general-settings`?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson nothing happened

Comment: Nothing as in a 500 error with a white screen? Wrong content? Btw, the first URL `/cPanel/abc` will also execute your rule since it matches the pattern.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson general-settings.php file is in the pages folder. Normaly if i write `http://localhost:8888/cPanel/pages/general-settings.php `then page will be displaying. But now nothing happened no 500 Interneatl Server error or any other error.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_GET)` in the end of your file and see what it actually contains.

Comment: Is `$_GET['page']` empty or what?

Comment: @Brigo $_GET['page'] is general-settings that is ok if page load without htaccess like `http://localhost:8888/cPanel/abc?page=general-settings`

Comment: You need to check your `$_GET` variable when it _doesn't_ work (_with_ your htaccess).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson When i use `RewriteRule ^cPanel/([\w-]+)/?$ abc.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]` page will showing index.php from the root folder.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I still checked `$_GET` variable without `htacess` it is getting `general-settings` . When i use `htaccess` it is redirecting me `index.php` file from `root` folder.

Comment: Show us your complete htaccess file. Also, can you please show us the file/folder structure of your app? What file goes where from the root folder.

Comment: Try this rule `RewriteRule ^cPanel/(.*)$ cPanel/abc.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: @Brigo It works with your rule thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error stands in the rule. Your actual rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^cPanel/([\w-]+)/?$ abc.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

which is missing `cPanel`, if you want to achieve `http://localhost:8888/cPanel/general-settings` as result

With this rule (which means: when you Apache match `cPanel/*anything*`, hit the resource at `cPanel/abc.php?page=*anything*`) it should work:

```
RewriteRule ^cPanel/(.*)$ cPanel/abc.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score -1):

**Test this code**

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteRule ^cPanel/(.+)/?$ abc.php?page=$1
```

**url:** http://localhost:8888/cPanel/general-settings